# Bug in Facebook's Security Model

Tags: facebook

It seems that Facebook has a bug in their security model in that it has incorrectly identifies my computer as an "unknown" computer. (I've always logged in from the same machine.) In response, my account has been locked. I am prompted to verify the account by answering a  security question to which the answer has been forgotten. (It never offers any alternate question.) So the program/procedure seems to be "in effect" in an endless loop. Since emails to any of the various facebook groups go unanswered, this is an attempt to find a potential solution before abandoning facebook and any pictures, time and interest that has been invested so far.